# Can AIR BLOCKS be part of your ME network?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm having an issue with my ME system resetting when I'm not around, supposedly due to chunkloading issues.

I have several(3) wireless ME Access Points set up. The Access Points themselves are chunkloaded, but I'm fairly sure their range extends outside of my chunkloaded area. Will the unloading of the chunks that my wireless range extends to reset my ME Network and force it to loose its Crafting Jobs?

Comment: they shouldn't when you access the network with the wireless it just checks whether you are close enough to an access point

Comment: Try setting up a chuckloader to keep the chunks loaded at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AE just cheks if you are near enough to an access point for the network you are trying to connect to.